# Java compiling error for merging 2 sets of arrays

Tags: java, merge

Can someone please help me out with my homework? For some reason Java doesn't recognize my inputs

with the following error repeated:

```
Merge.java:25: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Scanner
location: class Merge
        Scanner a = new Scanner( System.in );
        ^
```

---

```
public class Merge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = { 1, 1, 4, 5, 7 };
        int[] b = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };

        int[] mergedArray = merge(a, b);

        for (int i = 0; i < mergedArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(mergedArray[i] + " ");
        }

    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {

        // WRITE CODE HERE

        int[] mergedArray = new int[a.length() + b.length()];

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        while (i < a.length() && j < b.length()) {

            if (a[i] < b[j]) {
                mergedArray[k] = a[i];
                i++;
            }

            else {
                mergedArray[k] = b[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        while (i < a.length()) {
            mergedArray[k] = a[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        while (j < b.length()) {
            mergedArray[k] = b[j];
            j++;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: seems like you are missing imports for Scanner : java.util.Scanner

Comment: Also, there is no `length()` method on an array, it's just `length`.

Comment: Please include the correct source code. Your sample code doesn't even use Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, and here is what I did to fix it.

1. Import the Scanner Library by including `import java.util.Scanner;` at the very top
2. Change `length()` to `length`.
3. Add `return mergedArray;` at the end of the `merge(int[] a, int[] b)` method.

Recompile it, and Run it.
Good luck.